# Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader failed unexpectedly Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation)

Tags: android, ios, macos, flutter, mac-in-cloud

Whenever I try to build and run a flutter project, this error shows up for the iOS device. I am using a macincloud and the simulator.

The app would successfully launch but would lose the connection or not launch at all in some cases.

I tried using both Android studio and VS Code but both shows the same error:

```
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader failed unexpectedly
Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation).
```

`flutter doctor` Summary

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3.3)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.46.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```